# problem with equation in markdown

Tags: markdown

How can I code this equation in markdown? I'm trying this in marktext

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a question about typesetting with TeX? Please explain a bit in that case.

Comment: @mickep is that oke now?

Comment: I did not down vote, but I suggest that you instead of providing an image code give the code of a minimal example. From what I see now the only thing that comes to my mind is that there probably should be a period after the `\right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You can fix it as such:

```
$\left[ \begin{array}{} x + y = 1 \\ x - y = 2 \end{array} \right$
```

The second parameter for the array environment is needed.

Comment: That should be `\right.` for the matching place marker.  (Probably a typo here, but without a matching *something*, that's an automatic error message.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton In the software the original poster is using, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @barbarabeeton tks u it worked